# Javascript - one button call ajax and one button submit form using html5 form validation

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a form that I want to use the required attribute, which I believe is from html5 to make sure the user puts in a name before running the ajax to send and email and stays on this page (index.php). The form below works. My problem is that I can't figure out how to a a button called pay that submits the form to pay.php like a regular form submit so the user ends up on pay.php when they click "pay" and I want the form validation to still occur when they click pay and on pay.php I can grab the contactName from the post.

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" class="tm-contact-form">                                
  Name: <input type="text" id="contactName" name="contactName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required/>
  <button type="submit" id="inquire-button"  class="btn btn-primary">Inquire</button>
  <div id="mail-status">&nbsp;</div>
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$("inquire-button").on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});

$("#contactForm").on('submit',function(e){
  sendContact();
  e.preventDefault();
});

function sendContact() {
  jQuery.ajax({
  url: "mailer.php",
  data:'contactName='+$("#contactName").val(),
  type: "POST",
  success:function(data){
    $("#mail-status").html(data);
  },
    error:function (){}
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

EITHER don't use the click, but only the submit event

```js
$("#contactForm").on('submit', function(e) {
  const $btn = $(document.activeElement);
  if ($btn.is("#inquire")) {
    console.log("Inquire clicked")
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "mailer.php",
      data: 'contactName=' + $("#contactName").val(),
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#mail-status").html(data);
      },
      error: function() {}
    });
  }
  else console.log("Pay clicked")

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contactForm" method="post" class="tm-contact-form">
  Name: <input type="text" id="contactName" name="contactName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required/>
  <button type="submit" id="inquire-button" class="btn btn-primary">Inquire</button>
  <button type="submit" id="pay" class="btn btn-primary">Pay</button>
  <div id="mail-status">&nbsp;</div>
</form>
```

OR use a button

```js
$("#contactForm").on('submit', function(e) {
  console.log("Submitted (pay)")
})

$("#inquire-button").on("click", function() {
  if (!this.form.checkValidity()) {
    this.form.reportValidity()
    return
  }
  console.log("Inquire clicked")
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "mailer.php",
    data: 'contactName=' + $("#contactName").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#mail-status").html(data);
    },
    error: function() {}
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contactForm" method="post" class="tm-contact-form">
  Name: <input type="text" id="contactName" name="contactName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required/>
  <button type="button" id="inquire-button" class="btn btn-primary">Inquire</button>
  <button type="submit" id="pay" class="btn btn-primary">Pay</button>
  <div id="mail-status">&nbsp;</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! The 2nd suggestion worked form me. But just out of curiosity... the 1st one didn't. In your first suggestion, how do I get the form to post to pay.php? If I add action=pay.php to the form tag, then it does that but then the other button doesn't stay on the same page like I want.